# What is the difference between `git diff topic1 topic2 ^master` and `git diff topic1..topic2 ^master`?

Tags: git

I am trying to compare changes that were made on two different branches that forked from master at two different commits. So, I do not want to see the changes that were made on master in-between the two branches.

I have tried `git diff topic1 topic2 ^master` and `git diff topic1..topic2 ^master`, but I find that I get different results - specifically, a different set of changed files - despite the fact that the documentation states that `git diff a b` and `git diff a..b` are the same. (https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_examples)

What is the difference between the two commands, and which one can I trust? Or, am I simply doing this incorrectly? Is there a better way?

Comment: The proper man page is [git rev-list](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list). The first example is exactly the first part of your question, with explanations, while the second example refers to the second part.

Comment: Thanks, user3159253! That doesn't exactly answer my question, but it's a good reminder of the `git rev-list` command and how it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The revision parsing code for `git diff` is overly permissive, and then winds up doing the wrong thing with multiple arguments.  In some cases it mis-interprets its arguments if you give it more than two commit IDs and at least one of them is negated (as you are doing).  In particular, it winds up treating the (positive-ref, positive-ref, negative-ref) triple *as if* it were the three-dot syntax.

Several weeks ago, I submitted [a Git fix specifically for this](http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg280490.html), which (as usual) has been ignored (sigh).  Even with this fix, though, you can't get what you want.  Except for the even-more-special case of *combined* diffs—which still are not what you want—you can only have Git compare at most two *existing* trees already stored in the repository:

> I am trying to compare changes that were made on two different branches that forked from master at two different commits. So, I do not want to see the changes that were made on master in-between the two branches.

In other words, you have a commit graph that goes something like this:

```
          a--a--A      <-- feature-A
         /
...--o--*--o--o-...    <-- master
               \
                b--B   <-- feature-B
```

and you want to compare the tip-most commit of `feature-A`—i.e., commit `A`—to *what you would get* if you took the two commits that are exclusively on `feature-B` (commits `b` and `B`) and applied them to the commit I marked with a `*`, i.e., the point where `feature-A` branched off from `master`.

You *can* quite easily have Git compare the tree for commit `A` vs the tree for commit `B`.  This is what `git diff feature-A feature-B` and `git diff feature-A..feature-B` do.  But this is not what you want.

To get a diff between the tree for commit `A` and a (currently hypothetical) tree `B'` you must create a temporary branch,<sup>1</sup> and then cherry-pick the two `feature-B`-only commits onto `*`:

```
          a--a--A      <-- feature-A
         /
...--o--*--o--o-...    <-- master
         \     \
          \     b--B   <-- feature-B
           \
            b'-B'      <-- temporary branch
```

Now you really do have a commit `B'` with the tree that you get if you "take away" the two intermediate `master` commits, and *now* you can compare the tree for `A` against this new commit's tree.

---

<sup>1</sup>It is technically possible to do all this without a temporary branch, by constructing the hypothetical tree `B'` in the work-tree, without committing, using `git cherry-pick -n`, rather than as a series of commits on a temporary branch using `git cherry-pick`.  But commits in Git, including temporary ones on a temporary branch, are fast enough and cheap enough that this does not buy you much—and if some of the cherry-pick steps require resolving merge conflicts, it just makes everything that much more difficult.

Comment: I was scratching my head on this one. Another awesome answer torek. Every time I read one of your answers, I learn something.

Comment: @DavidN: Just luck that I ran into this bug when fussing with `a...b` syntax a few weeks ago.  When there is *no* merge base between two branch tips, it behaves very badly.

Comment: Maybe http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg280490.html would not be ignored if it was given with a patch implementing a test which illustrates the issue (and fails), followed by your patch (which makes the previous test works) (same for http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg216943.html)

Comment: @VonC: hm, I did have an actual test case for the stash fix, but I suppose I should convert it to Git's own test-case format.  I have not yet dived into any of Git's own test cases yet, as all I know for sure is some of them fail on my main system, causing the test run to stop anyway. :-)

Comment: "I should convert it to Git's own test-case format." Yes, that is how those contributions seem to work: a patch-test which shows the problem and fails, then the patch(es) implementing a fix.

Comment: And you can make them as PR, for submitgit to send those patches for you: https://submitgit.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this! Regarding your footnote, @torek, can this be achieved with `git diff a b -- $(git diff --name-only master...a)`? To be sure that no files were added, unknowingly, to the b branch, I run it again with `master...b`. I believe this accomplishes the same thing, but without the need for temporary branches or cherry-picks. Or, am I overlooking something?

Comment: @LouisPace: The list of paths after the `--` simply constrains the diff to show only those files. That may not be the same as comparing a hypothetical commit. For instance, suppose we have just one file `F`. In tip-of-`a` it begins with "hello", in `master` after `*` but before the fork for `b` it was changed to read `hello world` and a middle line was added or modified, and in tip-of-`b`. `F` has, added at the end, `goodbye`.  Diffing `a` vs `b` will show the modified `hello` and the added middle line *as well as* the final added line. (continued...)

Comment: If, instead of diffing `a` vs `b`, we copy the commits from `b` to `*`, and diff `a` vs the resulting commit, the only change we will see this time is the added `goodbye` line. Your "limit the set of files in the output" trick can work if and only if the modifications after commit `*`, in the commits that are on *both* `master` *and* `b`, do not touch any files also touched in commits that are only on `b`.

Comment: @torek I can see I didn't take everything into account, but your explanation makes perfect sense. Thank you very much for your time!