# How to make a Git branch from another branch and ignore unmerged files?

Tags: git, github

When I create a new branch feature2 from another branch feature1, it also contains changed files from feature1 that weren't merged with master. Is there a way to separate changes in feature1 and feature2?

Comment: Have you tried to `stash` the uncommitted files?  See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash.  Then you can create your new branch without those uncommitted files.

Comment: Those files were committed in another branch (feature1).

Comment: Why do you create feature2 from branch feature1 if you don't want the changes of feature1 to be contained in feature2? Just create feature2 from master and it will not contain anything from feature1.

Comment: The thing is that I want changes from feature1 in feature2 but I don't want changes from feature1 to be displayed as changes in feature2.

Comment: @Stan Are you concerned about extra commits in the log?  If so, you can just squash multiple commits you don't want into one commit.  You will still have that code, though.  But if you **COMPLETELY** don't want certain code, then you'll have to checkout that certain commit which doesn't have that code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to mark the branch feature2 as "do never show the changes from feature1 when comparing this branch". If that were possible, a problem would occur when merging feature2: Either the changes from feature1 would be merged - in this case stuff would be merged which is not shown in a diff. Or the changes from feature1 would not be merged, leading to problems if feature2 is based on those changes (e.g. a new function added in feature1 is called in feature2).

However you can show all commits which are part of feature2 but neither of feature1 nor of master:

```
git log ^feature1 ^master feature2
```

By adding the `-p` option you can also see the diff for each of the commits to review these changes.

Comment: This does work with `git log` but not with `git diff`: `git diff ^feature1 master feature2` does not do what you think it does. In fact it winds up diffing the commit identified by `feature1` against the commit identified by `feature2`, i.e., it does `git diff feature1 feature2` (I think—it might do `feature1` vs `master`; without running an actual test case I'm just going from memory). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/38648906/1256452 for why.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that my test case was too simple to see the problems with git diff. I removed that part from my answer and reduced it to the usage of `git log`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me what you want is to start off `feature2` on the most recent commit that is both in `master` and in `feature1`, so merging `feature2` to `master` before `feature1` won't introduce any commits from `feature1`. You can do this by using the [git-merge-base](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) command to find the most recent commit shared by two branches:

```
git checkout -b feature2 $(git merge-base --fork-point master feature1)
```