# Short hand for git changes on branch

Tags: git

```
git diff $(git merge-base origin/master HEAD)
```

gives the output I want. Is there a short hand version of that ?

```
git diff origin/master...
```

Gives the changes to HEAD (which do NOT include the working directory changes as the first command does)

I can alias the top command if there is no other short hand method

Comment: There is no shorthand syntax here for obtaining the merge base of `HEAD` vs `origin/master`, then diffing that merge base against the work-tree. It's `git diff` itself that takes over the "..." syntax, which actually parses into a three-or-more-entry set with one SYMMETRIC_LEFT flag, several SYMMETRIC_LEFT|UNINTERESTING flags (one per merge base), and one ordinary positive ref—in this case the normal, positive ref is HEAD—and then `git diff` diffs the UNINTERESTING-flagged commit, which is the merge base, against the positive-ref commit. (This breaks if there is not exactly 1 merge base.)

Comment: ok thanks for that :) If you make that an answer I will accept. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shorthand syntax here for obtaining the merge base of HEAD vs origin/master, then diffing that merge base against the work-tree.  You might as well use an alias or script.  (By the way, note the `@{u}` or `@{upstream}` syntax, which allows you to use the configured upstream of the `HEAD` branch instead of hard-coding `origin/master`.  This is of course only right if that's the actual upstream. :-) )

Note: it's `git diff` itself that takes over the `...` syntax, which—internally—parses into a three-or-more-entry set:

```
$ git rev-parse A...B
6557bf269bcd52a6a925d5b6af6f487fa281a215
457cac425f167ad32d14bb82abcf1eb9a3663569
^05ff1e9e04a60268403a064963e18a399421cb38
```

(names are changed, commit IDs are real—but note that `git rev-parse` does not print all the flags here) with one `SYMMETRIC_LEFT` flag, several `SYMMETRIC_LEFT|UNINTERESTING` flags (one per merge base), and one ordinary positive ref.  In your case, with `git diff origin/master...`, the normal, positive ref is (the commit ID for) HEAD.  Then, `git diff` diffs the `UNINTERESTING`-flagged commit, which is the merge base, against the positive-ref commit.  (This breaks if there is not exactly 1 merge base: [What is the difference between `git diff topic1 topic2 ^master` and `git diff topic1..topic2 ^master`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38648906/1256452))

Comment: what is the `@{u}` syntax ? I can't see it in the man or google for it very easily ?