# Why is the diff reversed for a merge commit with ^! parent notation

Tags: git, diff, parent, notation

Why does the the `^!` reverse the diff for merge commit?

From [Other ^ Parent Shorthand Notations](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_other_rev_parent_shorthand_notations)

> The `r1^!` notation includes commit `r1` but excludes all of its parents.
>   By itself, this notation denotes the single commit `r1`.

This correctly shows me the diff for a non-merge commit.

```
$ git diff <commit>^!
```

But for a merge commit, the diff is reversed.

```
$ git diff <merge-commit>^!
```

I get similar results for `difftool`.

Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that it is a bug.

You can see what `git diff` effectively sees by using `git rev-parse`.  Here's the `^!` suffix applied to an ordinary commit:

```
$ git rev-parse 699d47e1d^!
699d47e1d2777ad1c2a867671e35daa821769f29
^4aaf5b0b21ac1fc294066593ac5243b3eaff897b
```

and here it is applied to a merge commit:

```
$ git rev-parse 117ddefdb^!
117ddefdb4dfd9b40ae60967a7327754d8ce7a87
^5e5a7cd9327cdbe6b50b5a0ead9b2ee5fb30789c
^699d47e1d2777ad1c2a867671e35daa821769f29
```

When you supply the compressed notation to `git diff`, Git passes it through the same expansion code that `git rev-parse` uses.  Instead of printing it out, though, `git diff` then tries to back-interpret the result.  If there are two commit hashes (with various flags) it runs a diff between the two named commits.  If there are three or more, it does something different.

Related (but not quite the same): [What is the difference between `git diff topic1 topic2 ^master` and `git diff topic1..topic2 ^master`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38648906/1256452)

Comment: Is there an eta on fix? Just curious.

Comment: I don't think anyone cares enough to make this work. On the other hand, they might argue that it's a feature: if they ever take my fix for the other issue, you wind up with a combined diff, the same one you get with `git show`.

Comment: Honestly, I think the `commit^!` is perfect to diff merges at least from documentation. `commit~ commit` works for commits and merges but I find it less intuitive for merges.