# git diff/log and the order of start/end commits specified

Tags: git

When running `git log` or `git diff` it seems the order of how the commits are specified is important.

Tip of my branch is: **8ad4ff890446** and base of my branch is: **6e91a6615**

When I run git log from tip to base I get:

```
$ git log --oneline 8ad4ff890446..6e91a6615
d9b526fb ...
a5f4ad92 ...
af96bb6c ...
8d416ba9 ...
c7a37d4f ...
```

If I reverse the arguments and run git log from base to tip I get:

```
$ git log --oneline 6e91a6615..8ad4ff890446
2d6055e7 ...
656ac5b3 ...
3a4e2bbc ...
```

The last call is actually what I would expect - only 3 commits was introduced since base.

Why do I only get 3 commits (correct) when going from `base -> tip` compared to 5 commits when going from `tip -> base`?

Comment: It isn't "going from X to Y", it specifies "reachable from X but not from Y".

Comment: The word "base" is probably not a good idea to use as usually this word is used in the "base of the merge", which indicates which common commit between two branches is used to figure out which changes has been made. This base is along the history of the branch, and thus in such a scenario, both commands shouldn't list commits. I suspect by "base" you mean source branch, or upstream, the one you're going to merge back into when the branch is completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [double dot](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_double_dot) syntax doesn't mean "going from X to Y", it means this:

> The most common range specification is the double-dot syntax. This basically asks Git to resolve a range of commits that are reachable from one commit but aren’t reachable from another.

A very simple example to demonstrate your output would be this:

```
                             master
                                v
A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H---I
             \
              \-J---K---L
                        ^
                      branch
```

Here master is ahead of your branch by 5 commits and your branch is ahead of master by 3 commits.

In this case, this command:

```
git log branch..master
```

should list the 5 commits E-I, whereas this:

```
git log master..branch
```

should list the 3 commits J-L.

---

If you're on Windows you can open a command prompt and navigate to a temporary or new (empty) folder somewhere and then paste these commands in, executing them:

```
git init
for %f in (a b c d e f g h i) do (echo %f>test.txt && git add . && git commit -m "%f")
git checkout HEAD~5 -b branch
for %f in (j k l) do (echo %f>test.txt && git add . && git commit -m "%f")
```

Afterwards you can execute these commands and inspect the output

```
git log branch..master
git log master..branch
```

Comment: Ok so git log A..B actually means: return the sequence of commits that B is ahead of A?

Comment: That is in B but not in A, so yes, how B is ahead of A.

Comment: Ok I understand, now when I run git diff instead I seems I am getting the opposite behavior, e.g. to list the files modified in B but not in A I have to run git diff --diff-filter=d --name-only B A. I assumed the behavior of git log/diff was the same regarding the list of commits visited.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: `git diff` cheats; don't think of it as doing what `git log` does, because it doesn't.

---

Besides [Lasse V. Karlsen's (correct) answer on `git log`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45793361/1256452), you need to know that `git diff`(ab)uses both the two and three dot notations in a way that differs from every other Git command.

The syntax I find the most sensible with `git diff` is this:

```
git diff <commit1> <commit2>
```

This compares the stored tree for `<commit1>` with the stored tree for `<commit2>`, so it's quite straightforward to see how it works: in effect, Git extracts the two commits, then compares them.  The output is a series of instructions: add this line to file 1, remove that line from file 2, and remove file 3 entirely, perhaps.  If you apply those instructions to the tree for `<commit1>` you get the tree for `<commit2>`.

If you reverse the two commits, the diff gets done with the commits swapped, so you'll get instructions that read: *remove* that first line from file 1, *add* the second line to file 2, and *create* an all-new file3, with all-new contents.  These instructions will convert the tree for `<commit2>` into the tree for `<commit1>`.

So far so good—but what happens when you run `git diff <commit1>..<commit2>`?  The `git log` syntax implies that there may be *many* commits here, but `git diff` can't show you many commits.  The `diff` code mostly<sup>1</sup> just compares *two* commits, not some arbitrarily large number of commits.

The secret is that when given the `A..B` syntax, `git diff` *throws away the `..` part entirely*.  So it really does *exactly the same thing* as `git diff A B`.  If you reverse the two items, `git diff B..A`, Git does exactly the same thing as if you run `git diff B A`.

The really tricky part is what happens when you use the *three*-dot (or *symmetric difference*) syntax, `git diff A...B` or `git log A...B`.  Once again, `git diff` and `git log` differ (if I may use that word here :-) ).  With `git log` and its script-oriented sister command `git rev-list`, the three-dot syntax works [as advertised](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), producing the set of all commits reachable from exactly one of the two specified commits, excluding commits reachable "simultaneously" from both commits.

What `git diff` does instead, though, is to find the *merge base* of `A` and `B` and diff that against commit `B`.  [The code it uses to do this is flawed,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38649887/1256452) but works for most cases and most arguments.

---

<sup>1</sup>The word "mostly" is here because `git diff` will produce a *combined diff* in some cases, particularly when looking at a merge commit.  Combined diffs [are documented](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html#_combined_diff_format), but [in a rather scattered fashion](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html#_diff_format_for_merges), and are a bit tricky to describe well.  The key sentence about showing only *files modified from all parents* is only in that second linked section, where it is easy to miss when you're looking for the description about reading the output.